# Partial Derivative of the root of a polynomial with respect to its coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, partial-derivative

Suppose that I have a polynomial $p(x) = c_0+c_1x^{-1}+\ldots c_{N-1} x^{-(N-1)}$ with roots $x_0,\ldots,x_{N-1}$, how do I derive an expression for the partial derivative of the root with respect to the coefficient i.e. $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial c_k} \forall 0\leq i,k \leq N-1$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean for the $c_1x$ to be $c_1x^{-1}$, or the last to be $c_{N-1}x^{N-1}$?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Have corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_0$ be a root. Then $$p(x_0)=0=c_0+c_1x_0^{-1}+\cdots+c_{N-1}x_0^{-(N-1)}$$

Clearly any given root is a function of the coefficients of the polynomial. Deriving both sides with respect to $c_k$ gives

$$0=x_0^{-k}-k c_k x_0^{-k-1}\frac{\partial x_0}{\partial c_k}-\sum_{j\neq k}jc_j x_0^{j-1}\frac{\partial x_0}{\partial c_k}$$
by the product rule and chain rule.

Thus
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial x_0}{\partial c_k}&=\frac{x_0^{-k}}{\sum_{j} jc_jx_0^{-j-1}}\\
&=\frac{x_0}{\sum_{j}jc_jx_0^{k-j}}
\end{align*}

Comment: There is an error in computing the derivative. The second term in the second equation should be $k c_k x_0^{-(k-1)}\frac{\partial x_0}{\partial c_k}$

Comment: You are right! I'll fix it.